# Async Task for a peroid of time after closing the activity

Tags: android

I want to download 4 video file from web server.That i have used Asynctask to download files?what if the user leaves the application. will async task work for until the download complete? if not please send the code to manage that?

Comment: Use IntentService for your purpose.

Comment: can anyone send me the code, using Intent Service to download files in queue and it has to be killed after the downloads are completed.Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through `startService(Intent)` calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes for both of your questions. I tried it myself, but, actually, you should think about Service